# Inserting multiple instances does not work via DbSet.AddRange() in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core

I would like help to resolve an insertion of multiple instances of a C# class. I have an `IList<Operation>` to save in the database via Entity Framework Core and I have been using `DbSet.AddRange(entity)` to persist the list of objects.

However, only the last object in the list is saved in the database. All others are lost or ignored.

Below I show my code:

```
public virtual async Task AddMany(IList<TEntity> entity)
{
    DbSet.AddRange(entity);
    await SaveChanges();
}

public async Task<int> SaveChanges()
{
    return await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

What could be wrong or missing for me to be able to persist the entire list of objects?

Comment: Does database have a primary key?  With a primary key only one row with key value is allowed.  So if you are saving the same key multiple times only the last will be saved in the database.

Comment: Hi. I checked and the IDs are not being duplicated. I use GUID to generate the IDs.

Comment: I've seen this issue lots of times.  The only way for last item to be saved is when you are adding duplicate keys.

Comment: `AddRange` is nothing more than a shortcut to `foreach` + `Add`. Try replacing `DbSet.AddRange(entity);` with `foreach (var e in entity) DbSet.Add(e);` and see if still getting the described behavior. If yes, then something is wrong with your entity / configuration or data passed in `entity` argument, hence in order to help we would need [mre] .

Comment: Ivan Stoev, I tried using foreach but it still keeps saving only the last item in the list :(

Comment: What does that list contain in the first place? `Add` is fundamental to how EF works. If it failed the way you claim, every developer would have noticed. Does the list contain the same object multiple times?

Comment: As said, show sample content of `IList<TEntity> entity` (e.g. as JSON). What you observe is definitely not an EF problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem and will share it so that it can help other developers with the same issue. I simply added the following line of code `DbSet.AttachRange(entity);`. This allowed all objects in the list to be properly persisted in the database.

The result was the following:

```
public virtual async Task AddMany(IList<TEntity> entity)
{
    DbSet.AttachRange(entity);
    DbSet.AddRange(entity);
    await SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: There's no reason for this code. `Add` or `AddRange` will attach any detached entity in the `Added` state. This isn't a `works for me` situation. EF Core *depends* on how `Add` or `Update` work. Where did `IList<TEntity> entity` come from and what does it contain? Does it contain the same object multiple times?

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary proof. Until now though, there's only pseudocode. Post real code that compiles and demonstrates the claim. While one can assume that `Db` is a DbContext and `DbSet` is an unfortunate alias for one of the context's DbSets, we can't know. For all we know it may be a reference to DbSet in *another* context instance. Why not use `Db.TheActualSet.AddRange(entities)` and remove the confusion?